# How can I use css only and avoid JS for menu navigation?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a menu component.

The requirement is to do it without JS, but use css instead.
What I'm struggling with, is how to navigate using focus (Tab key)?

You can see it in the code snippet - you can set focus on the parent menu pressing `Tab`, but then when you try to keep pressing `Tab` to navigate in the submenu, it becomes invisible again (The parent loses focus)

Eventually, I would like the submenu to act like in the hover state, try to hover the example and you see what I mean.

Please note that I managed to solve it using `focus:within`, but since it is not supported in Edge&IE, and I don't want to use JS polyfills, I am looking for an alternative.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item:focus > .subItems {
  visibility: visible;
}

.item:hover  > .subItems {
  visibility: visible;
}

.subItems {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>focus helper</button>
<div class="container">
<nav>
  <ul class="items">
    <li class="item" tabIndex="0">
      <a href="#" class="link" tabIndex="-1">News</a>
      <ul class="subItems">
        <li class="item" tabIndex="0">
          <a href="#" tabIndex="-1">Politics</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" tabIndex="0">        
          <a href="#" tabIndex="-1">Sports</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: thanks, but I mentioned in the post that I want to avoid it.

Comment: It's not supported in IE, it's totally supported in edge. And if you want to support IE you will have to use Javascript. Or make it so that the menu is always visible. These are the two options you have.